# How to get notified that new message is sent in specified telegram channel with TLSharp?

Tags: c#, telegram, telethon, tlsharp

I need to handle new messages in specified channel of tg. I think that it is should be possible to do with TLSharp (or telethon on python), but I accept any other method or library.

I guess there should be a solution using client for tg RPC Api, but I can't find it.
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLSharp does not allow you to process incoming updates/messages as they come by.

This is possible with [WTelegramClient](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient) *(.NET library available on Nuget)* with the `client.OnUpdate` event.

See [here for a full example](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/Examples/Program_ListenUpdates.cs) showing how to handle/display update/messages.
You can then filter these update to show only those coming from a specific channel (see `peer` fields)

Note: TLSharp is no longer maintained and doesn't work correctly anymore, so I would recommend switching to WTelegramClient anyway.